# Prevent required:after content being on a new line

Tags: css

We currently use label.required:after on our forms to indicate required fields as follows:

```
<tr>
    <td><label for="loginName" tag="" class="required">Login name:</label></td>
    <td><input type="text" name="loginName" id="loginName" value="" maxlength="64" required="required" /></td>
    <td></td>
</tr>
```

This is marked up using the following CSS:

```
label.required:after {
    content:" *";
}
```

As the table changes size, it pushes some of the asterisks onto new lines of their own. Is there a way of stopping it doing this (unless the label itself wraps onto a second line).

Would prefer to just modify the label.required class if I can, but open to other methods if they solve the problem quite nicely.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Place a non-breaking space before the * instead of a normal space. Since you're working with CSS, you need to use an escape sequence `\00a0` instead of an HTML entity `&nbsp;`:

```
label.required:after {
    content:"\00a0*";
}
```